# Coroutine with a SupervisorJob - cancellation behaviour

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to implement some exception handling in my code so I've the following coroutine test code which launched from a fragment;

```
private val scoped = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())

...

val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        println("TAG-Caught $exception")
    }

scoped.launch(handler) {

        val job1 = launch {
            println("TAG-first job is running")
            delay(200)
        }

        testParentChildWithExceptionWithSupervision()

        launch {
            println("TAG-third job is running")
        }
    }
```

where the method `testParentChildWithExceptionWithSupervision` looks like;

```
suspend fun testParentChildWithExceptionWithSupervision() {

    supervisorScope {

        val job1 = launch {
            println("TAG-running first (inner) child")
            delay(200)
            throw ArithmeticException()
        }

        val job2 = launch {
            job1.join()
            println("TAG-First child is cancelled: ${job1.isCancelled}, but second one is still active")
            delay(200)
        }

        job1.join()
        println("TAG-second child is cancelled: ${job2.isCancelled}")

        println("TAG-ENDING")
    }
}
```

The output is as I expected;

[image]

The thing is as soon as I change `supervisorScope` to `coroutineScope` in the suspending function, I see that root scope (with the SpervisorJob) do not carry on with her childs;

```
suspend fun testParentChildWithExceptionWithoutSupervision() {

        coroutineScope {

            val job1 = launch {
                println("HH-doing first child")
                delay(200)
                throw ArithmeticException()
            }

            val job2 = launch {
                job1.join()
                println("HH-First child is cancelled: ${job1.isCancelled}, but second one is still active")
                delay(200)
            }
```

and I get this output instead;

[image]

So nothing seems to be carried on in the root scope after having an exception even the scope has a supervisor job. I bet I miss sth but not able to see it. Can someone please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Can you kindly be more clear on your question by providing more information on it?

Comment: Sure. My question is why the "scope" in the fragment does not carry on executing remaining child jobs (for instance, the last "launch" coroutine) once it's second child fails by throwing an exception. I'd expect that it to execute it as it's job is a SupervisorJob. But apparently I'm misunderstanding some semantics.

Comment: I have checked with your code using SupervisorJob and its executing second child the way you expect it to, that's why I asked. It would help if you provide a full code in question.

Comment: It's not the second job, it's the "third" (which is a launch coroutine).

Comment: What is `handler`? because if I removed `scope.launch(handler)` block then in case of `supervisorScope` third job always execute. That's why I asked you to provide all the necessary information in detail.

Comment: it's just an exception handler (updated the code). But why to remove it? That's the whole point of the question and removing it affects the structured concurrency that I try to achieve. So again, the job I expect to be executed is the last job which is - `launch {
            println("TAG-third job is running")
        }` coroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) on `suspend fun coroutineScope`, you'll find this:

> The method may throw a [...] corresponding unhandled `Throwable` if there is any unhandled exception in this scope (for example, from a crashed coroutine that was started with `launch` in this scope).

This is the case that happens in your code: the "first (inner) child" crashes with an unhandled `ArithmeticException`. This becomes the result of `testParentChildWithExceptionWithSupervision` and at the call site, nothing handles it. Therefore it proceeds to crash the parent as well — not through the mechanism of propagating coroutine cancellation, but through the basic exception mechanism. `SupervisorJob` makes no difference here, the main block of code completes abruptly with that exception unhandled, which is why you see it printed by the unhandled exception handler.

If you modify your code to do this:

```
    try {
        testParentChildWithExceptionWithSupervision()
    } catch (e: ArithmeticException) {
        println("ArithmeticException in main block")
    }
```

you'll see the main coroutine proceed until the end.

Comment: Yes cancellation is different from failure but I think this is still a bit awkward to me as the `launch` automatically propagates the exception upwards regardless you run `supervisorScope` or `coroutineScope` in the method and they cause different behaviours on the call site.

Comment: Note the fundamental difference: launch returns immediately, always with a successful result. There's no option for it to propagate the failure of the concurrent coroutine it started. coroutineScope awaits the completion of all children and propagates exceptions.

Comment: One last thing. You stated "nothing handles it.". But what about the handler set on the `scope.launch(handler) { ... }`? Would not it handle the exception?

Comment: It handles it only after it has already killed the coroutine. It just gives you a post-mortem.

Comment: We can then also say handling an exception has a kind of precedence over delivering cancellation signal. I mean if we don't handle it, then cancellation if not propagated internally by the coroutine machinery. And the generic handler won't help that much in this case as it's a "post-mortem" thing.

Comment: Whenever a coroutine gets cancelled due to an exception or an explicit `cancel` call, its parent Job receives a notification via a `childCancelled` call. So in that sense, cancellation/failure always propagates upwards. If, however, the parent job is waiting inside a `coroutineScope`, the `coroutineScope` function call will throw the exception it got from the child. If you leave that exception unhandled, then that will become the reason why the parent gets cancelled as well. Note that this story involves _additional_ mechanisms that may make it appear as if cancellation wasn't propagated.

Comment: "Whenever a coroutine gets cancelled due to an exception or an explicit `cancel` call, its parent `Job` receives a notification via a `childCancelled` call" I doubt this is entirely correct as, in the code, I see that the job just returns `true` form the `cancelParent` function without reaching `childCancelled` call if cancellation is considered "normal".

Comment: Yes, actually explicit cancellation with `CancellationException` is not propagated, it seems.